# Add X-Forwarder-For HTTP header to HAProxy

Tags: haproxy

I use `HAProxy 1.3.26` on my `CentOS 5.8` to proxy all requests to a dedicated server. I use HAProxy just to proxy HTTP and HTTPS to a single server, so no load balancing.

My `haproxy.cfg` is rather simple:

```
global
        log 127.0.0.1   local0
        log 127.0.0.1   local1 notice
        maxconn 4096
        user haproxy
        group haproxy
        daemon

defaults
        log global
        option dontlognull
        option httpclose
        option forwardfor
        clitimeout 60000
        srvtimeout 60000
        contimeout 5000
        retries 3
        option redispatch

listen http 192.168.0.1:80
        mode tcp
        option tcplog
        maxconn 10000
        server web01 192.0.1.13:80 maxconn 5000

listen https 192.168.0.1:443
        mode tcp
        maxconn 10000
        server web01 192.0.1.13:443 maxconn 5000
```

where:

```
192.168.0.1 - server where HAProxy is installed
192.0.1.13  - server to which HTTP requests are forwarded
```

I would like to see the clients' IP addresses in my `Apache 2.2.3` access logs. This option is usually achieved by adding the `HTTP X-Forwarded-For` header and then reading it in the web server logs. So, I've added the following lines to httpd.conf:

```
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-agent}i\"" combined
LogFormat "%{X-Forwarded-For}i %l %u %t \"%r\" %s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-agent}i\"" combined_forwarded
SetEnvIfNoCase X-Forwarded-For "." from_proxy=1
CustomLog logs/access_log combined env=!from_proxy
CustomLog logs/access_log combined_forwarded env=from_proxy
```

The problem is the only logged IP address is `192.168.0.1` (HAProxy server). I've tried different configurations, read documentation, googled but still can't understand why the clients' IPs are not logged.

I feel like I'm missing something simple, as the configs are very straightforward. Please help to correct the configs if possible.

Thank you for any help.

Comment: Seems like the `SetEnvIfNoCase` is never triggering.  Can you try ditching the conditionals on that, make all logging occur in the `combined_forwarded` format, and see what's logged?

Comment: And also make the two log formats differ in some other aspect, just in order to be absolutely sure which of the two shows (it's conceivable the second shows, but X-Forwarded-For could somehow be the haproxy's IP address), and use tcpdump to sniff the traffic between haproxy and apache to see whether the x-forwarded-for header is ok.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please do not forget that this will not work for the https proxy since haproxy will not be able to mangle the contents of an encrypted session. You might also want to check the mod_rpaf module for Apache which makes all this easier.